# ¿Cómo llenar un listview de Xamarin Android desde SQLite?

Tags: xamarin, listview, android-sqlite, xamarin.android

Tengo una vista con un listview, quisiera poder llenar ese listview cuando la vista se ejecuta, mi base de datos está en sqlite, se genera a partir de una clase llamada proveedor:

```
 public class Proveedor
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int IdProveedor { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string RazonSocial { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string NombreCorto { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string RFC { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string CalleNumero { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string Colonia { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string Ciudad { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string Estado { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public int CodigoPostal { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string Pais { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public int Telefono1 { get; set; }
    //Puede ser nulo
    public int Telefono2 { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public string NombreContacto { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public int PlazoDias { get; set; }
    //Puede ser nulo
    public string Observaciones { get; set; }
    [NotNull]
    public bool Borrado { get; set; }
}
```

Éste es el controlador donde hago mi insert a la base de datos:

```
public void InsertProveedor(Proveedor provee)
        {
            string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "kobit.db3");
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
            provee.Borrado = false;
            provee.CalleNumero = "Mirasol 501";
            provee.Ciudad = "Morelia";
            provee.CodigoPostal = 58160;
            provee.Colonia = "Felix";
            provee.Email = "Oscar.com";
            provee.Estado = "Michoacán";
            provee.NombreContacto = "Oscar";
            provee.NombreCorto = "Oscarin";
            provee.Observaciones = "recomendaciones";
            provee.Pais = "México";
            provee.PlazoDias = 1;
            provee.RazonSocial = "venta de armas";
            provee.RFC = "NXCO919191";
            provee.Telefono1 = 477546879;
            provee.Telefono2 = 0;
            db.Insert(provee);
        }
```

y éste es mi Activity:

```
        namespace KobitAndroidBeta
    {
        [Activity(Label = "Proveedores")]
        public class Proveedores : Activity
        {
            ListView lstProveedores;
            SQLiteConnection db;
            protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
            {
                base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Proveedores);


                ProveedorController prove = new ProveedorController();
                Proveedor pro = new Proveedor();


                prove.InsertProveedor(pro);

                //var items = prove.SelectProveedores();
                //var lstProveedores = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
                //lstProv

eedores.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);
            LoadList();

        }
        private void LoadList()
        {
            string dbPath = Path.Combine(System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "kobit.db3");
            var db = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath, SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite);
            var tblProveedor = db.Table<Proveedor>();

            ArrayList lst = new ArrayList();

            foreach (var prove in tblProveedor)
            {
                lst.Add(prove.Estado);
            }

            string[] arr = (String[])lst.ToArray(typeof(string));
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                      new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, arr);

            lstProveedores.Adapter = adapter;
        }
    }
}
```

Me está tronando en la parte del adapter, en lstProveedores.Adapter = adapter;
no se si estoy haciendo bien la parte de llenar el listview de esa manera, espero me pudieran ayudar

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Cómo llenar un listview xamarin android desde db sqlite?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/97880/c%c3%b3mo-llenar-un-listview-xamarin-android-desde-db-sqlite)

Comment: Sera porque `lstPorveedores` es null? Ve que comentaste el codigo donde buscabas la lista `//var lstProveedores = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);`

Comment: Toda la razón @Einer, estaba ya tan estresado que no inicialice el ListView

Comment: Lo pondre como respuesta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seguro te lanza `NullReferenceException` porque comentaste el codigo donde buscabas la lista:;

```
//var lstProveedores = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
```

Remueve el comentario:

```
var lstProveedores = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView1);
```